# How to add password matching validation in vuetify?

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a profile form which have two fields
`password` and `rePassword`. basically, Both of them should be the same.

I tried using different codes found on the web and different approaches.  Some of them worked but. It did'nt actually fit in with the code.

Here is the piece of code:

Profile.vue:

```
<v-layout>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6>
          <v-text-field                        
            v-model="password"
            :append-icon="show ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
            :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'"
            name="password"
            label="Enter Password"
            hint="At least 8 characters"
            counter
            @click:append="show = !show"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>

          <v-flex xs12 sm6>
            <v-text-field            
              v-model="rePassword"
              :append-icon="show1 ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
              :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
              :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
              name="input-10-1"
              label="Re-enter Password"
              hint="At least 8 characters"
              counter
              @click:append="show1 = !show1"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
```

This is how the script looks like:

Profile.vue (script):

```
data() {
      return {
        show: false,
        show1: false,
        password: 'Password',
        rePassword: 'Password',
        rules: {
          required: value => !!value || 'Required.',
          min: v => v.length >= 8 || 'Min 8 characters',
          emailMatch: () => ('The email and password you entered don\'t match')
        },
        emailRules: [
          v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
          v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid'
        ],
        date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
        menu: false,
        items: ['male', 'female'],
        address: '',
        title: "Image Upload",
        dialog: false,
        imageName: '',
        imageUrl: '',
        imageFile: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      pickFile() {
        this.$refs.image.click()
      },            
          onFilePicked(e) {
        const files = e.target.files
        if(files[0] !== undefined) {
          this.imageName = files[0].name
          if(this.imageName.lastIndexOf('.') <= 0) {
            return
          }
          const fr = new FileReader ()
          fr.readAsDataURL(files[0])
          fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            this.imageUrl = fr.result
            this.imageFile = files[0] // this is an image file that can be sent to server...
          })
        } else {
          this.imageName = ''
          this.imageFile = ''
          this.imageUrl = ''
        }
        },
    }
      ,
      validate() {
        if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
          this.snackbar = true
        }
      },
      reset() {
        this.$refs.form.reset()
      }
```

How do I add a password matching feature in the validation using vuetify.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply using Vee-validate:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <form>
      <v-text-field
        ref="password"
        type="password"
        v-model="pass"
        v-validate="'required'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('pass')"
        label="Pass"
        data-vv-name="pass"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="pass2"
        type="password"
        v-validate="'required|confirmed:password'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('pass2')"
        label="Pass 2"
        data-vv-name="pass"
        required
      ></v-text-field>

      <v-btn @click="submit">submit</v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="clear">clear</v-btn>
    </form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  $_veeValidate: {
    validator: 'new'
  },

  data: () => ({
    pass: '',
    pass2: "",
  }),
  methods: {
    submit () {
      this.$validator.validateAll()
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result)
        })
    },
    clear () {
      this.pass = ''
      this.pass2 = ''
    }
  }
})
```

Remember to install `vee-validate` first and restart your local-server.

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/dBXKMP?editors=1010)

[link to docs](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/getting-started.html)

Comment: Property or method "errors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render..

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collect' of undefined"............
 Cannot read property 'collect' of undefined.....

These are the error coming in when i plugged in your code

Comment: Did you install vee-validate first and restart server? https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/getting-started.html

Comment: Possible to add this line too in the Answer? Someone dumb enough like me might miss it. :p

Answer (score 38):

You can define custom rules:

```
computed: {
    passwordConfirmationRule() {
      return () => (this.password === this.rePassword) || 'Password must match'
    }
}
```

and use it

```
 <v-flex xs12 sm6>
    <v-text-field            
      v-model="rePassword"
      :append-icon="show1 ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
      :rules="[rules.required, rules.min, passwordConfirmationRule]"
      :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
      name="input-10-1"
      label="Re-enter Password"
      hint="At least 8 characters"
      counter
      @click:append="show1 = !show1"
    />
  </v-flex>
```

Comment: This code generate a error : [Vuetify] Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'object' instead

Comment: @VarinderSohal, are you sure your `rule` is correct? It must be `:rules="[passwordConfirmationRule]"`

Comment: In case its still not working, try this: `computed: {
    passwordConfirmationRule() {
      return (this.password === this.rePassword) || 'Password must match'
    },
}`

Answer (score 12):

very easiest way is
using v-model (password and confirm_password), no need to use computation

Rule

```
:rules="[v => !!v || 'field is required']"
```

Or

```
:rules="[(password!="") || 'field is required']"
```

in password

```
<v-text-field label="Password*" v-model="password" type="password" required   :rules="[v => !!v || 'field is required']"></v-text-field>
```

confirm password field
Rule

```
 :rules="[(password === confirm_password) || 'Password must match']"
```

code:

```
 <v-text-field label="Confirm Password*" v-model="confirm_password" type="password"  required   :rules="[(password === confirm_password) || 'Password must match']"></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 5):

VeeValidate is great for form validation but in my opinion is overkill for resolving this question when it can be achieved in Vuetify alone.

Following on from @ittus answer, you need to remove the arrow function in `passwordConfirmationRule` to access *this*:

```
      return this.password === this.rePassword || "Password must match";
```

See [this codesandbox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-austin-0pgw3) (also now using Vuetify 2.x)

Comment: This works, but It's throwing the same error in the console.

Comment: @MikelGranero do you mean the "[Vuetify] Rules should return..." error mentioned on ittus's response?  This is working in the Codesandbox example above, can you debug your code to see what the values are when they're being compared and/or returned?

Answer (score 1):

This works right for me!

```
// template
<v-text-field v-model="password" label="password"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field v-model="confirmPassword" :rules="confirmPasswordRules" label="confirmPassword"></v-text-field>
      
// script
computed: {
  confirmPasswordRules() {
    const rules = [(this.password === this.confirmPassword) || "Password must match."];
    return rules;
   },
 }
```

Comment: works fine for me ! ty

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clean solution definitely, but works fine.

```
    <v-text-field
        type="password"
        v-model="password"
        :rules="passwordRules"
        required
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
        type="password"
        v-model="passwordConfirm"
        :rules="passwordConfirmRules"
        required
    ></v-text-field>
```

```
let globalPassword = "";
```

```
    watch: {
        password() {
            globalPassword = this.password;
        },
    },
```

```
    passwordConfirmRules = [
        (v) => v === globalPassword || "Password must match",
    ];
```