# Vuetify password confirmation not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to create a registration mask and I want to make sure that the two passwords the user types in are identical before continuing but I cannot figure out how to do it in Vuetify.

I have tried creating a rule for it but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

Template:

```
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-flex md5>
          <v-text-field v-model="pw1"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            :rules="pwdRules"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
      </v-col>

      <v-col>
        <v-flex md5>
          <v-text-field v-model="pw2"
            label="Confirm Password"
            type="password"
            :rules="pwdConfirm"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>

      </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

Script:

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
      pwdRules: [ v => !!v || 'Password required' ],
      pwdConfirm:[ v => !!v || 'Confirm password', v => v === this.pw1 || 'Passwords do not match'],
    }),
```

The funny thing is if I use this code snippet `v => v === this.pw1 || 'Passwords do not match'` it even makes Vuetify ignore the first rule which checks if the field is empty or not. If I delete this snippet the rule works correctly and checks if the field is empty but it obviously doesn't check if the two passwords are identical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add password matching validation in vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642635/how-to-add-password-matching-validation-in-vuetify)

Comment: It isn't. I read that question like 5 times since yesterday and the first answer literally says "it's simple just use vee-validate" but doesn't explain how to make the confirmed: attribute work, all I ever get is an error. 

The second answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Vue component's `data` [must be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function), not an arrow function since an arrow function doesn’t have a `this`. From Vue.js [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods):

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as
> `created: () => console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`. Since an arrow function doesn’t have a `this`, this
> will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through
> parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` or `Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function`.

2. You are referencing `pw1` and `pw2` which are not defined in `data`.

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ysemeniuk/pen/pozpyzE)

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Could you please tell me why it didn't work the way I tried?

Comment: @Andor Németh, actually I am wrong and this can be done without `computed` `pwdConfirm`. You have another bugs, I'll edit my answer and Codepen now

Comment: I tried your codepen but all I ever get is a blank page when I insert your javascript code. Note: I imported 'vue' and 'vuetify'

Comment: @Andor Németh, what errors do you see in your browser's console?

Comment: The error was "You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build." But I already solved it by changing `import Vue from 'vue'` to `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'` and it works now. Again, I appreciate your help!